# Set a variable and check equality in one line

Tags: java

I'm creating a maze program to get some more practice in Java.  I have a method that moves the player, and it returns a `boolean` value if the move was successful (i.e. it didn't run into a wall).

Here is the method in question:

```
public boolean move(Direction direction) {
    if(currentLocation == (currentLocation = maze.movePlayer(this, direction))) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Obviously, this will always return false.  I was wondering if there is a way to check if `currentLocation` didn't change (or is equal to the returned value of `maze.movePlayer(...)` and set them equal if they aren't).  I don't know if it is possible to do this without calling the method twice or using a local variable.

I hope this makes sense!

Comment: No, there isn't -- but why would you? It's much more readable to do it the "old-fashioned way" anyway.

Comment: There is no point really, I enjoy shorthand and was wondering if there was a shorter form for this.

Comment: Learn to enjoy readability instead.

Comment: Is currentLocation an Object or a primitive?

Comment: Okay, OP -- it looks like your original answer _won't_ always return false.  Your original idiom, awkward as it was, worked.

Comment: `currentLocation` is an `Object` that is basically a holder for two integers that represent a coordinate.

Comment: @LouisWasserman why does it work? Also, shouldn't it (probably) have a `.equals()` implemented instead of using `==`?

Comment: @trutheality Yes, I had an `.equals()` written but neglected to use it.  @LouisWasserman How does it work?  Or how did you test it, rather?  I can't seem to make it work in my implemented code.

Comment: @trutheality: `int x = 3; System.out.println(x == (x = 5));` prints `false`.  I think it has to do with the order-of-operations being that the `x` on the left hand side is evaluated before the assignment.

Comment: @LouisWasserman yep. Looked it up: [JLS 15.7.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7.1) is actually called "Evaluate Left-Hand Operand First."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the conditional operator:

```
public boolean move(Direction direction) {
     return (currentLocation == (currentLocation = maze.movePlayer(this, direction))) ? false : true;
}
```

Comment: What does the conditional operator get you here that a simple `!` wouldn't?

Comment: I'm not sure I get this answer.

Comment: No, because it would still only return false, as currentLocation would be set already, and obviously be equal to itself.

Comment: I tested it, and this answer appears to work, much to my surprise -- but it's certainly awkward to read even so.  @Wires77: I think it has to do with order of operations, where the left-hand side of `currentLocation` is evaluated before the assignment.

Comment: Nothing, really... I wasn't thinking as simple as that :-P Inverting the boolean result is a much better approach.

Comment: @Wires77 Java knows better ;) It's pretty opaque, though; I don't think I'd use this, *or* `!(x == (x = newX))`.

Comment: How does this work if the original doesn't? Confusing... `:|`

Comment: @minitech The original *does* work; I'm still trying to figure out what the question is.

Comment: @DaveNewton: I guess it's so obvious that it will return `false` that the OP asked before actually trying it. (I can't say I blame him/her, though. That's really unobvious functionality!)

Comment: @Dave Newton/all, my understanding of the question is to turn the body of the method in question to a single line. Please correct me if I am mistaken.

Comment: @DaveNewton @LouisWasserman I'm not sure how it was tested, but `currentLocation` is set first when I debug it.  If it helps, `currentLocation` is an Object that simply holds two `int` values as x and y.

Comment: @KevinMangold Who said that wasn't the question?

Comment: @Wires77 What happens if you compare objects correctly, using `.equals`, after writing an appropriate `.equals` method? (Unless you're caching or something that would allow `==` to work.)

Comment: @DaveNewton The same problem occurs.  It's still just setting `currentLocation` before the evaluation.  That's why I was curious how Louis tested it.

Comment: @Wires77 Moved comment to "answer" for space reasons.

Answer (score 2):

This works as you expect, using a single line, assuming a reasonable `equals` method.

*(I pass a `Location` instead of transforming a `Direction`, but the mechanics are identical.)*

```
public class Main {

    private Location loc = new Location(0, 0);

    public boolean move(Location newLoc) {
        return !loc.equals(loc = newLoc);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main m = new Main();

        // Not same; moved from 0, 0: true--move successful.
        System.out.println(m.move(new Location(42, 69)));

        // Same; moved from 42, 69: false--move failed.
        System.out.println(m.move(new Location(42, 69)));

        // Not same; moved from 42, 69, 0: true--move successful.
        System.out.println(m.move(new Location(69, 42)));
    }
}
```

This uses a simple `Location` implementation; note the `equals`, auto-generated by IntelliJ:

```
public class Location {

    private int x;
    private int y;

    public Location(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }

        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }

        Location location = (Location) o;

        if (x != location.x) {
            return false;
        }

        if (y != location.y) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Hmm, okay I see that it does work as intended.  I have an error elsewhere in my original code that causes mine not to work the same.  Thanks a lot for your help (Even if I change this to be more readable anyway, haha)!

Comment: @Wires77 Just don't use the ternary `?:` because there's no point--negate the conditional.

Comment: Out of curiosity I looked up why this works and the answer is in [JLS 15.12.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.4) -- the target reference is determined before the arguments are evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this using temp variable:

```
public boolean move(Direction direction) {
    Location oldLocation = currentLocation;
    currentLocation = maze.movePlayer(this, direction));
    return !oldLocation.equals(currentLocation);
}
```

Comment: Right, but the question was how *not* to use a temp :)